# Конфликт двух классов в разных пространствах имён C++

Tags: c++, классы, namespace

Есть два класса с одинаковыми именами, которые находятся в разных файлах ( но с одинаковыми названиями ) в разных папках. Классы обёрнуты в разные пространства имён, и, читая ответы на другие вопросы, конфликта между ними не должны произойти. Но при компиляции выдаёт ошибку "Ссылка на неразрешённый символ" на конструктор одного из классов. Также, если я уберу определение одного из классов нажимая на "Перейти к определению" он перебрасывает меня другому классу ( в Visual Studio 2019 ). Что я делаю не так?

---

Вот примерно ситуация

```
// Folder1/file.h

namespace A
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test();
    }
}

// Folder1/file.cpp

#include "file.h"

A::Test::Test()
{
    // Определение
}
```

```
// Folder2/file.h

namespace B
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test();
    }
}

// Folder2/file.cpp

#include "file.h"

B::Test::Test()
{
   // Другое определение
}
```

```
A::Test test1 = A::Test();  // Работает
//B::Test test2 = B::Test();  // Если раскомментировать, будет ошибка
```

---

И вот скрин ( Как видно, открылось определение класса в другом namespace, а слева структура проекта ), возможно он прояснит ситуацию
[image: Скрин экрана]

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в другом, но на данный момент эти классы очень похожи друг на друга и вероятно причина в их конфликте

Comment: Воспроизвести не получается, но есть подозрение, что сбивают компилятор с толку одинаковые имена файлов в разных папках - надо смотреть, как у вас проект записан...

Comment: Проверьте, что в файлах file.h  используются разные include-guard-ы (  `#ifdef/#define` ).

Comment: @Harry Да, дело было в файлах, надо было сделать их с разными названиями, причём файлы именно классов, вот например одиночные файлы заголовков сейчас у меня с одинаковыми именами, и это не мешает компилироваться

Comment: @Chorkov разные

Comment: @Chorkov Тогда бы у него не компилировалось. А тут - не линкуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio при сборке генерирует объектные файлы для каждой единицы трансляции в промежуточной папке сборки (Intermediate Directory) независимо от нахождения .cpp файла этой единицы трансляции в иерархии папок и выбирает для них имя `<имя_исходного_файла_без_расширения.obj>`. Соответственно имена единиц трансляции необходимо выбирать уникальными в рамках одного проекта, даже если они располагаются в разных папках, иначе будете получать конфликты и прочие проблемы при сборке.